# How do I prepare fresh magento install (ver. 1.8.1) for local theme developement?

Tags: magento, configuration

Just installed a fresh copy of Magento and I would like to know what settings/configurations have to be made in order to begin theme development. I'm running php 5.4 on a mac and for coding the theme I will use SCSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new theme folder and theme package folder (optional) as followig
 `app/design/frontend/{theme package name}/{theme folder name}/`

then create two folders `layout and template` and work in them.

Then create the skin related folders in `skin/frontend/{theme package name}/{theme folder name}/` and place all your theme related `css and images` here.
Note that you have to keep the theme package name same for both.

To activate this theme on the site, log-in to your admin panel, go to
 `system >> configurations >> Design` and click the `Package` Tab and enter your theme package name then open the `Theme` tab beneath it and enter the `Template, Skin and layout` theme folder names, if the theme folder name is same for all of them then just enter it in the `Default` field and leave others empty and save the settings. Now clear the site `Cache` by going to `system >> Cache Management`, select all the options and click `Submit` button and reload the frontend. The new theme will be in action.